# How to solve ode of the form $ a_n(y')^n + a_{n-1}(y')^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 y' + a_0 =0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$
a_n(y')^n + a_{n-1}(y')^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 y'+a_0 =0
$

I am also unclear on how to describe this as it is not nth order. The polynomial being in the derivative is not something that I think I have seen before.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it kind of looks like you should solve the polynomial for $y'$, then solve for $y$

Comment: Do you mean $\cdots + a_1 y^\prime + a_0$ at the end?

Comment: Would make sense @parsiad

Comment: @NeoDarwin: encouraging OP to edit the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **TLDR.** All *continuously differentiable* solutions of the ODE are of the form $y(t) = c + tz$ where $z$ is a (possibly complex) root of the corresponding polynomial.

Let $y:[0,T)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $T\leq\infty$ be a *continuously differentiable* function satisfying the ODE
$$
a_{n}(y^{\prime}(t))^{n}+\cdots+a_{1}y^{\prime}(t)+a_{0}=0.
$$
By the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), if $a_{n}\neq0$, the corresponding polynomial
$$
a_{n}r^{n}+\cdots+a_{1}r+a_{0}
$$
has $n$ complex roots, call them $z_{1},\ldots,z_{n}$. We can re-express the ODE as
$$
\left(y^{\prime}(t)-z_{1}\right)\cdots\left(y^{\prime}(t)-z_{n}\right)=0.
$$
By the above, $y^{\prime}(t)=z_{k(t)}$ where $k(t)\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for all $t$.
In fact, $t\mapsto z_{k(t)}$ must be constant since otherwise continuous differentiability is violated. We conclude that $y(t)=c+tz_{j}$ for some $j$.

Answer (score 5):

Well. As pointed out in the comments by Seth.

Let us consider an example

\begin{align}
(y')^2+2y'+1=0
\end{align}
then it follows $y' = -1$ so $y = -t+C$.

So, in general, you will get $y'=$ const. Then $y=\text{const}. t+C$.

Comment: What if it does not have real roots?

Comment: Then you have a complex constant. If you only want real solutions, then you can drop all the complex solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer and logical.